# Cache Is Not Drawing, But Layer Is On?

Tags: arcgis-server, cache, arcgis-10.3

I have a cached map service that was published on ArcGIS Server 10.3. The tiles were built with no error. Using the ArcGIS/Bing Maps scale, I set the tiles to build to 1:577,791, I also set the extent of the layer to turn off in beyond 1:577,791. I zoom into the 1:577,791 scale, the layer is still checked on but no tiled data draws. When I zoom into the next scale. 1:288,895 the cached layer turns off/is grayed out, and no data appears, as it should.

Any thoughts as to why there is no data drawing at the 1:577,791 scale? I would like the tiles to draw at that scale.

Comment: is your cache store properly referenced in the map service?

Comment: Did you verify the image files actually exist in the following directory: arcgisserver/directories/arcgiscache/NameOfYourService

Comment: The cache is built and draws for all other zoom levels. For a temporary work around, I set the MXD scale range to 'Don't show layer when zoomed in beyond 1:577,700', and when zoomed into the 1:577,791 scale the cached layer draws. But if I were to change the layer scale range to 1:577,791 (a predefined ArcGIS/Bing Maps Scale) the cache still does not draw. The image files do exist.